# Removing unused java classes from workspace can increase performance of web server?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, webserver

I am working on a project in which code is taken from other sources/team and most of java classes are unused and increasing my war file size. Will removing these unused Java class files can improve my webserver performance as it is always high and perform slow? I understand it is a silly question still I want to take suggestion for it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No it wouldn't, Classes are loaded as needed or when manually loaded by a classloader.